# Using the TP-Link and AC

Tags: smart-home

I bought a TP-Link HS100.

I would like to connect my Fridgedaire through the wall Air Conditioning unit to it.

Can I use the TP-Link to operate it?

Comment: Update the question with the power usage details of the Air Conditioning usage, IIRC AC units draw high current which may well be out of the safe range fro the switch.

Comment: can you operate the AC by unplugging the AC for a while and then plugging it back in?